# insert function result in rubish number

Tags: c++, vector, insert, containers

I don't know why I get these rubish numbers in my vector container?
here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
 std::vector<int> ivec = {2,3,5,7};
 std::vector<int>::iterator it = ivec.begin();
 std::vector<int>::iterator pos = ivec.begin()+1;
 ivec.insert(pos,444);
 while(it != ivec.begin())   
{
 std::cout << *it << std::endl;
 it++;
} 
 return 0;
}
```

here is the result :
0
0
370638864
22056
0
0
49
0
2
444
3
5
7

Comment: When asking a code related question, you always need to add a tag for the language you're using. Please [edit] your post to do so.

Comment: I think the problem is not with insert but with the iterator or maybe the condition of while

Comment: Take a look at your while loop. Also, you inserted in to your `vector` which will invalidate your `iterator`.

Comment: ok , even if the loop is  : while(it!=ivec.end()) , I will still have rubish numbers , but as you said the insert function , invalidate my iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `insert` a value in to a container (a `vector` in this case) you can invalidate any `iterator`'s you currently have if the `vector` needs to resize. If the `vector` doesn't resize only `iterator`'s before the insertion remain valid. The past the end iterator is also invalidated.

Also, your `while` loop condition should be `it != ivec.end( )`.

That being said, make your life easy and just use a range-based for loop.

```
int main( ) {
    std::vector vec{ 2, 3, 5, 7 };
    vec.insert( vec.begin( ) + 1, 444 );
   
    for ( auto value : vec ) {
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    }

    // If you really want to use iterators you can do this.
    // Do this after the insertion into the vector.
    for ( auto it{ vec.begin( )}; it != vec.end( ); ++it ) {
        std::cout << *it << '\n';
    }
}
```